# How can I use a JavaScript function that is located on a website on my own web page or application?

Tags: javascript, python

My university's website has a link that uses a function that returns a unique URL to a new page which contains a student timetable.

```
<a
  name="UV_SS_DERIVED_UV_PR_CLASS_TT_BTN"
  id="UV_SS_DERIVED_UV_PR_CLASS_TT_BTN"
  ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode"
  tabindex="17"
  onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);"
 href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'UV_SS_DERIVED_UV_PR_CLASS_TT_BTN');"
class="PSHYPERLINK">Print Class Timetable</a>
```

The function that I am interested in is: `javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'UV_SS_DERIVED_UV_PR_CLASS_TT_BTN');`

I am new to everything JavaScript and I'm trying to create an application which needs that student timetable through the unique URL.

Can I take this function from the website/link and use it in my application as if it was requesting the data from my university's server?

I did complete a version of my application in C# using selenium , but I am now 
working on  a python version that uses the requests package and it will be very simple and easy if I  can use that function as if it were my own.(I do not want to use selenium here!) I am open to changing to another language other than python if the need be.

If any more information is needed , please do ask!

Comment: No you won't be able to do that. You'll need to write your own function.

Comment: Look where that function is defined and try to replicate it. It probably just makes an ajax request or something.

Comment: You can not call a js function from a different website

Comment: @mplungjan "Material which is clearly indicated as owned by the University of Auckland may only be used for "not-for-profit" educational purposes or private research and study" . This is also not my university. And I did say I do not want to use Selenium in my project.

Comment: Ok, the code is identical